# Docker container has not set GOPATH correctly

Tags: docker, go

I have a problem when I try to run my app in a Docker container. It is running fine with a simple `go run main.go`, but whenever I build an image and I run the docker container, I got the error of `panic: html/template: pattern matches no files: *.html`, so I guess GOPATH is not properly set in the docker container (tho I use this same docker file from other projects and I don't have any problems). I am a little lost here, since this method I been using already for a while without problems.

I am using gin as a framework for develop.

The docker file is:

```
FROM golang:alpine as builder

RUN apk update && apk add git && apk add ca-certificates 
# For email certificate
RUN apk add -U --no-cache ca-certificates

COPY . $GOPATH/src/github.com/kiketordera/advanced-performance/
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/kiketordera/advanced-performance/

RUN go get -d -v $GOPATH/src/github.com/kiketordera/advanced-performance

# For Cloud Server
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags="-w -s" -o /go/bin/advanced-performance $GOPATH/src/github.com/kiketordera/advanced-performance

FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/advanced-performance /advanced-performance
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/kiketordera/advanced-performance/media/ /go/src/github.com/kiketordera/advanced-performance/media/

# For email certificate
VOLUME /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
COPY --from=alpine /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

EXPOSE 8050/tcp

ENV GOPATH /go
ENTRYPOINT ["/advanced-performance"]
```

Main function is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    i18n "github.com/suisrc/gin-i18n"
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
)

func main() {
    // We create the instance for Gin
    r := gin.Default()

    /* Internationalization for showing the right language to match the browser's  default settings
    */
    bundle := i18n.NewBundle(
        language.English,
        "text/en.toml",
        "text/es.toml",
    )

    // Tell Gin to use our middleware. This means that in every single request (GET, POST...), the call to i18n will be executed
    r.Use(i18n.Serve(bundle))

    // Path to the static files. /static is rendered in the HTML and /media is the link to the path to the  images, svg, css.. the static files
    r.StaticFS("/static", http.Dir("media"))

    // Path to the HTML templates. * is a wildcard
    r.LoadHTMLGlob("*.html")

    // Redirects when users introduces a wrong URL
    r.NoRoute(redirect)

    // This get executed when the users gets into our website in the home domain ("/")
    r.GET("/", renderHome)
    r.POST("/", getForm)
    // Listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080 (for windows "localhost:8080")

    r.Run()
}
```

The full project can be found in https://github.com/kiketordera/advanced-performance, is a simple website rendering with i18n and a POST form-handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GOPATH`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable) is not relevant; it's used to "resolve import statements" and plays no role when running an executable (unless your code references it specifically!). The `WORKDIR` is the issue here.

[`FROM`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) "clears any state created by previous instructions". This includes the `WORKDIR`. For example if you use the docker file:

```
FROM alpine:3.12
WORKDIR /test
copy 1.txt .

FROM alpine:3.12
copy 2.txt .
```

The final resulting image will have file `2.txt` in the root folder (and no `/test` folder).

In your `dockerfile` you are copying the `media` folder to `/go/src/github.com/kiketordera/advanced-performance/media/` on the assumption that the `WORKDIR` will be set; but that is not the case (it defaults to `/`). Simplest fix is to change `COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/kiketordera/advanced-performance/media/ /go/src/github.com/kiketordera/advanced-performance/media/` to `COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/kiketordera/advanced-performance/media/ /media/`.

You are also accessing files from the root folder so need to copy these in with `COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/kiketordera/advanced-performance/*.html /` (or similar). Given that you are doing this it's probably best to put everything (the exe, html files and media folder) into a folder (e.g. `/app`) to keep the root folder clean.

Note: There is no need to set `GOPATH` in the second image; as mentioned above it's not relevant when running the executable. I'd recommend using modules (support for GOPATH will probably be [dropped in 1.17](https://blog.golang.org/go116-module-changes)); this would also enable you to considerably shorten your paths!

Comment: I tried your solution and unfortunately does not work :/

Comment: Have updated my answer (downloaded your repo and it starts up OK with this change).